# Get JS script source when loading from 307 redirected source

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-307

Case is that:

1. My script inserts `<script>` in `<head>`, pointing to *src1*.
2. The back-end does 307 redirect from *src1* to *src2*.
3. Script then loads *src2*.

But when I use this code, I'm getting *src1*.

```
var s = document.createElement("SCRIPT"), 
    h = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0]; 
    s.charset = "UTF-8";
    s.src = url;
    s.async = true;
    s.type = "text/javascript";     
    h.appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function() {
      console.log(this.src)
    }
```

How can I get the *src2*?

Comment: You might want to check if the redirect is still in effect. If you happened to test this and then switched on redirection, your browser might be using a cached version of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

this.src is the src url you have set on your script tag, what you get back is the source from the temporarily redirected (307) script.

If you visit the src1 url and copy the redirect url from the response using fiddler or dev tools on your browser, you can set the that url directly in your code.

Comment: The redirecting url would be dynamicly-changed (in case of some parameters, like this:  src2&param=1, src2&param=2, src2&param=3 and so on.

Comment: yes, actually its not possible to get the redirect location within an XHR object, its handled earlier. I removed it form answer after reading up.

Comment: why do you need the redirect url?

Comment: O, it's a question for my archtector :)

Comment: Query string parameters are retained when redirected, so if add the parameters to the old URL they will be carried forward to the redirected url